# Convert string a double in a word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro for Word 2013 that does the following: the macro should capture the value of a cell of a word table and then add another value and paste the result in another cell of the same table.

[image]

My code so far is:

```
Sub prueba()
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

Dim entero1 As Double, entero2 As Double

Dim resultado As Double

Dim tabla1 As Table
Set tabla1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

a = tabla1.Cell(Row:=1, Column:=3).Range
entero1 = CDbl(a)
End Sub
```

But when I run it I get an error 13

[image]

To evaluate the error add the following two lines to validate if the data type obtained in "a" was a string

```
MsgBox (TypeName(a))
MsgBox (a)
```

And I got the following

[image]

[image]

I believe that the CDbl function does not finish converting the string to double because as they see the chain has a small square, what is not like to erase it so that the conversion is achieved.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try using `Val(a)` - that should ignore non-numeric parts of the string.

Comment: Instead of .Range try using .Value

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for your alternative, I use val() function and I do it. Please  You cant move your coment to an answer to mark the question as answered

Comment: @DavidG.  A Word `Cell` object doesn't have a `Value` property.  (Before I was willing to submit an answer recommending `Val` as a solution, I decided I had better google to see whether there actually **was** a better property than `Range` to use to get at the data - and there doesn't appear to be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of extracting just the numeric portion of the `Range` would be to use the `Val` function, e.g.

```
entero1 = Val(a)
```

If the string `a` contained, for instance, `123.23XYZ4567` then `Val(a)` would return the number `123.23`.

That should ensure that the non-numeric character that you are getting at the end of your `Range` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by YowE3K is elegant and has my vote. For further information:

That 'small square' is the *end of cell marker* which is part of `Cell.Range.Text` (`.Text` is the default property returned when returning a range object is inappropriate).

To actually *remove* the end of cell marker (`Chr(13) & Chr(7)`) you can use something like this:

`?CDbl(Replace$(Selection.Range.Cells(1).Range.Text, Chr(13) & Chr(7), vbNullString))`

A possible advantage of this approach is that it may provide better opportunity to trap errors if you are only expecting numeric characters.